# combine multiple rows in pyspark dataframe into one along with aggregation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below df with 2 rows which I want to combine into one row.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------+--------+---------------+
|                 vid|                 sid|pvid|                 cid|             orderId|         cartId|storeId|anchor_item|substitutes_1|substitutes_2|substitutes_3|substitutes_4|substitutes_5|impressions_sub_item_1|impressions_sub_item_2|impressions_sub_item_3|impressions_sub_item_4|impressions_sub_item_5|click_sub_item_1|click_sub_item_2|click_sub_item_3|click_sub_item_4|click_sub_item_5|preferred_sub_item|preferred_sub_rank|search_query|preferred_sub_source|     prefType| date_id|event_timestamp|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------+--------+---------------+
|526CC6AF-6A62-405   |911D8EC7-5B1F-4AD   |    |170836c4b25e4b0f9   |67374d42-024c-430   |200010858176654|    742|   14940752|         null|         null|         null|         null|         null|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|       842643501|            null|            null|            null|            null|          10849171|                 2|            |                P00N|SELECTED_PREF|20230427|  1682593258203|
|526CC6AF-6A62-405   |911D8EC7-5B1F-4AD   |    |170836c4b25e4b0f9   |67374d42-024c-430   |200010858176654|    742|   14940752|         null|         null|         null|         null|         null|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|            null|        10849171|            null|            null|            null|          10849171|                 2|            |                P00N|SELECTED_PREF|20230427|  1682593276038|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------+--------+---------------+
```

I have done that as below

```
cols_to_merge = [f.first(x, ignorenulls=True).alias(x) for x in _final_df1.columns[8:23]]
_final_df1.groupBy(_final_df1.columns[:8]+ _final_df1.columns[23:29]).agg(*cols_to_merge)
```

But now I want the max value in column event_timestamp to be also part of the combined row. How can I get that??

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|                 vid|                 sid|pvid|                 cid|             orderId|         cartId|storeId|anchor_item|preferred_sub_item|preferred_sub_rank|search_query|preferred_sub_source|     prefType| date_id|substitutes_1|substitutes_2|substitutes_3|substitutes_4|substitutes_5|impressions_sub_item_1|impressions_sub_item_2|impressions_sub_item_3|impressions_sub_item_4|impressions_sub_item_5|click_sub_item_1|click_sub_item_2|click_sub_item_3|click_sub_item_4|click_sub_item_5|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|526CC6AF-6A62-405   |911D8EC7-5B1F-4AD   |    |170836c4b25e4b0f9   |67374d42-024c-430   |200010858176654|    742|   14940752|          10849171|                 2|            |                P00N|SELECTED_PREF|20230427|         null|         null|         null|         null|         null|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|                  null|       842643501|        10849171|            null|            null|            null|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: On what columns you want the groupBy to be applied to ? You can just do df.groupBy(col1, col2, ..).agg(sum("event_timestamp"))

Comment: Can I do it in the same line? ```_final_df1.groupBy(_final_df1.columns[:8]+ _final_df1.columns[23:29]).agg(*cols_to_merge)```

Comment: what do you mean by *cols_to_merge ? I thought you want the max event_timestamp ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add max to the aggregation definition:
`cols_to_merge = [f.first(x, ignorenulls=True).alias(x) for x in _final_df1.columns[8:23]] + [f.max(f.col("event_timestamp")).alias("event_timestamp")]`